# Installing GCC compiler on Windows 7 through Git Bash?

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, git-bash

Does anyone know how to use Git Bash to install GCC, or how to install GCC and then register it with Git Bash?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

If executing ccommands through the cli is difficult to you, why are you trying to install a compiler cloning its sourcecode using git, through the command line?

Use an installer, its much simpler. You could use [the MinGW enviroment installer](http://www.mingw.org/), which includes GCC.

Comment: The question was not about how to install a compiler from source.  The question is about "git bash" a specific environment that's part of git for Windows.

Comment: See for instance, https://superuser.com/questions/701141/how-to-add-more-commands-to-git-bash-shell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686842/using-gcc-through-git-bash

Comment: In addition to what Brian Minton said, there's nothing from the question (even in its original unedited form) to indicate that "executing ccommands through the cli is difficult" for the OP.

Comment: This post is destructive and doesn't answer the question.